# Aplicar interfaces en C# para vincular con base de datos

Tags: c#, sql, interface, mvp

Tengo este gran problema y es que además de que soy nuevo en esto de programar, me cuesta bastante. El tema es el siguiente, necesito aplicar MVP a un pequeño programa de escritorio que estoy desarrollando y para ello necesito desvincular total mente la capa de vista con la creación de objetos. Por ejemplo, en el codigo siguiente tengo la creacion de la db y tengo que realizar una igualdad, cómo lo hago aplicando interfaces? Muchas gracias!

```
private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
        {
            Paciente obj = pacienteBindingSource.Current as Paciente;
            if (obj != null)
            {
                if (db.Entry<Paciente>(obj).State==System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached)
                {
                    db.Set<Paciente>().Attach(obj);
                }
                if (obj.PacienteID == 0)
                {
                    db.Entry<Paciente>(obj).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
                }
                else                   
                    db.Entry<Paciente>(obj).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

                db.SaveChanges();
                gridPacientes.Refresh();
                pControls.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mirate este tutorial por si te es de ayuda hacerca de [MVP](http://miguelaup.azurewebsites.net/mvp-pattern-part-1/)

Comment: antes de iniciar con patron MVP Implementa desarrollo a n-capas https://ves-sandola.blogspot.com/2013/07/programacion-en-capas-con-un-ejemplo-en.html

Answer (score 0):

El modelo vista controlador, te permite reutilizar código, en este caso te ayuda a no tener que escribir el código para conectarte en la base de datos en cada nueva clase que lo necesitas.

Ejemplo:

**Clase Conexión**

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
public class Conectar {
    
    public string usuario = "root";
    
    private string a = "0000";
    
    private int aux;
    
    public MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection();
    
    public void Asignar(string c) {
        contrase;
        a = c;
    }
    
    public void conectar() {
        conexion = new MySqlConnection();
        try {
            conexion.ConnectionString = ("server=localhost;user=" 
                        + (usuario + (";password=" + contrase)));
            (a + ";database=hotel;port=3306");
            conexion.Open();
            // '   MsgBox("Conectado")
            aux = 1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            MsgBox(ex.Message);
        }
        
    }
    
    public void Cerrar() {
        try {
            conexion.Close();
            MsgBox("sesion cerrada");
            aux = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            MsgBox(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Cuando necesites abrir la conexión a la base de datos puedes llamarlos usando herencia o declarando el objeto dentro de la clase.

Herencia:

> Class Registro: Conectar{
> } 
> conectar() <-- llamando al objeto

Llamando al Objeto

> Conectar obj = new Conectar()
> obj.conectar() <-- llamando al objeto

De esta forma tienes acceso a los objetos dentro de la clase Conectar.

Cuando quieras hacer consultas, insertar, actualizar o eliminar te recomendaría crear por cada tabla que tengas en la base de datos una clase dentro de tu proyecto con el nombre de la tabla, de esta manera lo puedes organizar mejor tu proyecto.